# compute Chi-Square (χ2) Statistic from comparing different Expected Frequencies

Tags: r, chi-squared

I ran into a problem and I hope someone can help me.

```
Observed<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,249,454,54,22,3,6,2),ncol=2, byrow = F)
```

[image]

```
Expected<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,284,358,123,17,4),ncol=2, byrow = F)
```

[image]

I have two matrices similar to the above, in which the first column is the numerical values and the second column is their frequencies. I want to merge the second column of each matrix so that their numerical values are the same so that I can compute Chi-Square (χ2) Statistic.
Actually, I mean that the resulting matrix should be as follows:

[image]

I repeat this several times and actually want to compare my expected frequency with the observed frequency each time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `merge` to join the matrices and substitute 0's for the `NA`'s.

```r
Observed<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,249,454,54,22,3,6,2),ncol=2, byrow = F)
Expected<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,284,358,123,17,4),ncol=2, byrow = F)

merge(Expected, Observed, by = "V1", all = TRUE)[-1] -> res
res[] <- lapply(res, \(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))
names(res) <- c("Expected", "Observed")
res
#>   Expected Observed
#> 1        8        9
#> 2      284      249
#> 3      358      454
#> 4      123       54
#> 5       17       22
#> 6        4        3
#> 7        0        6
#> 8        0        2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

But with expected counts of zero, the divisor in the chi-squared statistic is zero and the statistic is infinity:

```
sum((res$Observed - res$Expected)^2/res$Expected)
#[1] Inf
```

So don't do a full join, a left join is the right one.
The first test is computed by hand following the original Pearson formula, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test). The other two are R's `chisq.test` result without and with simulated p-values.

```r
merge(Expected, Observed, by = "V1")[-1] -> res2
names(res2) <- c("Expected", "Observed")

chisq <- sum((res2$Observed - res2$Expected)^2/res2$Expected)
chisq
#> [1] 70.6093
df <- nrow(res2) - 1L
pchisq(chisq, df, lower.tail = FALSE)
#> [1] 7.652696e-14

chisq.test(res2)
#> Warning in chisq.test(res2): Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
#> 
#>  Pearson's Chi-squared test
#> 
#> data:  res2
#> X-squared = 41.384, df = 5, p-value = 7.849e-08

chisq.test(res2, simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 2000)
#> 
#>  Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on 2000
#>  replicates)
#> 
#> data:  res2
#> X-squared = 41.384, df = NA, p-value = 0.0004998
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, dear Rui Barradas. Your solution was beneficial. I substitute 1's for the NA's.  In this case, the problem of expected counts of zero is solved.

Comment: @Tayeb But you must ask yourself how do you justify that, to suddenly, after joining  the two data sets, have at least one expected observation.

Comment: Dear Rui, yes, you are right. It is also important to justify this work. Anyway, this is perhaps the most basic and simple trick to solve the problem of zero expected frequency. And probably other better solutions can be found.